# Why such weird behavior from my switch statement?

Tags: java, switch-statement

Take the following code written in Java:

```
choice = keyboard.nextByte();

        switch (choice)
        {
            case (byte) 4:
                System.out.print("Input the layout type: ");
                layoutType = keyboard.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Input the layout name: ");
                layoutName = keyboard.nextLine();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

When I run the program, I get the following:

> Input the layout type: Input the layout name:

I get prompted for both inputs all at once!  Why is that?  Shouldn't the program stop at where it says "`keyboard.nextLine()`"?  It does that outside of the `switch` statement but not while inside of it.  Why does prompting the user for input inside of the `switch` statement cause this weird behavior?

===================================
UPDATE:

Yes, that's right.  `keyboard` is an instance of the `java.util.Scanner` class.

Comment: Can you show the declaration of the `keyboard` object?

Comment: some where question is unclear. Kindly refine it, secondly, Case should be Int, thats what I guess, it should not be BYTE

Comment: Try putting 
`while(!keyboard.hasNextLine());`
before each nextLine() calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are inputting a newline in order to read the byte, and the newline is somehow considered input for the subsequent call to `readLine()`. Add a dummy `readLine()` after `readByte()` to solve this:

```
choice = keyboard.nextByte();
keyboard.readLine(); // dummy readline
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `keyboard` is an object of `java.util.Scanner`, the problem lies in the following.

Firstly, you read a byte using `nextByte()`, thus only the byte value is taken as input. The remaining values, here in your case the newline character is remaining in the input stream. It is read by the `keyboard.nextLine()` as input and returned. So an empty string is returned by that line. So, you might want to put an extra `nextLine()` call to discard that new line as follows:

```
System.out.print("Input the layout type: ");
keyboard.nextLine();
layoutType = keyboard.nextLine();
System.out.print("Input the layout name: ");
layoutName = keyboard.nextLine();
```